# Retornar JSON com data e hora

Tags: php, json, oracle

Estou com um problema pra retornar o json com data e hora o código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT CRED_NUMERO, MOV_DATAHORA FROM APOIO.LOG_CREDENCIAL_APOIO A WHERE A.CRED_NUMERO = 10734568 AND TRUNC(MOV_DATAHORA) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)";
$conn = oci_connect('xxx', 'xxx', '127.0.0.1/DBUAM');
$dados = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($dados, OCI_DEFAULT);

$linhas = array();
while($l = oci_fetch_assoc($dados)){
    $linhas[] = $l;
}

$json = (json_encode($linhas));
echo $json;
?>
```

O resultando do json é esse:

> [{"CRED_NUMERO":"10734568","MOV_DATAHORA":"26-AUG-15"},{"CRED_NUMERO":"10734568","MOV_DATAHORA":"26-AUG-15"}]

Na tabela está assim:
[image: Retorno SQL oracle via PL/SQL]

Se vocês perceberem o resultando do JSON mostra somente a DATA sendo que o que mais importa pra mim é hora.
Como formatar?

Comment: Acho que o seu problema está mais relacionado ao banco de dados que você está usando e a sua consulta SQL. Você pode informar qual é o seu banco?

Comment: O banco de dados utilizado é Oracle

Comment: No select, acredito que vc precise formatar a data diferente do padrão, [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Comment: @VictorSued Testa trocar `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` para `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'dd/MM/RRRR HH:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
$sql ="SELECT CRED_NUMERO, TO_CHAR(MOV_DATAHORA,'HH24:MI:SS') MOV_DATAHORA FROM APOIO.LOG_CREDENCIAL_APOIO A WHERE A.CRED_NUMERO = 10734568 AND TRUNC(MOV_DATAHORA) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)"
```

Se vc quiser recuperar somente a hora ou substitua para

```
TO_CHAR(MOV_DATAHORA,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Para pegar a data e hora. O padrão nas configurações do PHP deve estar em outro formato

Comment: Finalmente alguém que sabe do que está falando, deu certo muito obrigado!